# Encrypted VoIP communication using the integrated Android 2.3 SIP stack

Tags: android, encryption, sip, rtp

I'm currently working on a project where I have to implement a secure VoIP communication between Android 2.3 (or higher) phones. The connection is established through a Kamailio server.

The requirement is that the SIP API provided by Android (since version 2.3) is used (if possible).

I think the biggest problem is that the connection is made from classes in the [android.net.rtp](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/x/android/android/9/p/android.net.rtp) package. But all these classes don't belong to the **public API**, therefore I cannot extend these classes and make my own changes to them.

**Now my question:** Is it still somehow possible to establish an encrypted connection by using SRTP (or ZRTP for that matter)? And if so, how should I approach that?

If it is **not possible** to do with the SIP API from Android, what would be a good alternative to do so?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android.net.rtp is public as of Android 3.1. If you are developing for 3.1 or later then you can extend from these, otherwise you'll need to implement your own.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. Now the only problem is that almost no device has Android 3.1 yet. And a lot of them won't ever receive it... Any suggestions for a good, already available, open source SIP stack?

Comment: It's not the SIP stack that you need. SIP is only used to negotiate a connection between two endpoints, it's the RTP stack that you need.

Comment: Here are open-source stacks I used:

Comment: Here are open-source stacks I use in Android: [RTP/RTCP](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/efflux) and [SIP](http://jsip.java.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Android 3.1 just released. These classes are now marked as available since API level 12